# Get pageID in DNN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

Just I wanted to ask how can I get the pageID from the DNN database.

Say I have the page, http://www.Website.com/pagename.aspx, on my website.  What table and fields would I query to get the Page ID from the DNN Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no PageID, there are TabIDs, if you're doing it in the database you would use

```
select tabId from tabs where tabname = 'pagename'
```

If you're developing modules, your module should inherit from PortalModuleBase and you will have direct access to the TabId property.